# What does -e do in this if-clause in Perl

Tags: perl, if-statement

I am looking through some Perl code and I got to this part:

```
foreach (@somevar) {
  if (-e "$_/$anothervar") {
      $boolflag=1;
      last;
  }
}
```

Yet I can't figure out what -e does. I am thinking the string afterwards is a path (deriving from its structure) but that's as far as I understand what is happening.

I looked for -e in the Perl help, but I don't understand how `-e` from this definition would work in an if-clause.

```
-e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong definition. That's a description of the command line switch for the perl executable.

You need to see the [perldoc for -X](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html):

> A file test, where X is one of the letters listed below. This unary operator takes one argument, either a filename, a filehandle, or a dirhandle, and tests the associated file to see if something is true about it.
>
> …
>
> ```
> -e  File exists.
> ```

Comment: Oh I see! Is there a way to see this *perldoc* from the terminal? Similar to `perl --help`?

Comment: That's a particularly annoying `perldoc` for being hard to find. But it's inherited from shell, so the manpage on `test` says mostly the same things. But `perldoc -f -X`  should do it.

Comment: @bram `perldoc -f -X`

Comment: `perldoc -f -X`.  `-f` means "function" and `-X` is the "name of the function", which it isn't really, but that's how it is.

Comment: Thanks all. You're all very fast today!

Comment: @BramVanroy Actually you can do `perldoc -f -e` (works for any of the file test operators, e.g. `perldoc -f -d`, `perldoc -f -T`, etc.)